# How to reference view objects inside a list?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a method to set a `listener` to each of my `views` inside a list like:

```
    private fun setListeners() {

    val clickableViews: List<View> =
        listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text,
    box_four_text, box_five_text)

    for(item in clickableViews){
        item.setOnClickListener{makeColored(it)}
    }
}
```

`box_one_text`, `box_two_text` and so on are the `id` of the views inside my xml file and I'm trying to set a color of it when they are clicked like:

```
   fun makeColored(view: View) {
    when (view.id) {

        // Boxes using Color class colors for background
        R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
        R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

        // Boxes using Android color resources for background
        R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)
        R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
        R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)

        else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
    }
}
```

the problems is that all of the elements inside the `list` are all red lines or can't reference by the list

Comment: Use a RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, the list type is wrong. You said that `box_one_text` and `box_two_text` are the view id. View id type is `Int`, so you should change the list to list of `Int`

```
val clickableViews: List<Int> =
    listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text,
box_four_text, box_five_text)
```

Then, to apply a click listener to each of the id, you need to find the view using `findViewById`

```
for(item in clickableViews){
    findViewById<View>(item).setOnClickListener{makeColored(it)}
}
```

Or if you use view binding, you can follow below code:

```
val clickableViews: List<View> =
    listOf(binding.boxOneText, binding.boxTwoText, binding.boxThreeText,
binding.boxFourText, binding.boxFiveText)
for(item in clickableViews){
    item.setOnClickListener{makeColored(it)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private fun setListeners() {

    val clickableViews: List<Int> =
        listOf(R.id.box_one_text, R.id.box_two_text, R.id.box_three_text,
    R.id.box_four_text, R.id.box_five_text)
    
    for(item in clickableViews){
        findViewById<View>(item).setOnClickListener{makeColored(it)}
    }

}
```